# Google maps bounds/zoom not working when parent div is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a large page of user data that is formatted for ease of use using accordion areas.
Click on the accordion control and the relevant information is shown. Click it again and it is hidden.

One of these accordions has a google map inside it with multiple pins.
When the parent accordion `div` is hidden bounds/zoom has no effect. When it is visible bounds/zoom works.

I can only imagine that the DOM has the collapsing parent `div` set to zero height and therefor Google Maps 'sees' this as zero all the way down the stack and sets bounds based on a zero height and width accordingly.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wjebusfL/1/

The default is to have the accordion closed. When you click the open button you will see that the map contains two markers but the zoom is way off.

If you comment out the display and opacity lines in the css for `.accordianarea`

```css
display: none;
opacity: 0;
```

You will see the accordion in an open state by default and the map bounds/zoom working OK.

Is there any way to 'force' the google map to render correctly with the accordion closed?

Answer (score 0):

#### New answer:

After digging a little deeper, I've found that the [`MapOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.minZoom) has a `minZoom` option:

> **minZoom** (optional)
>
> The minimum zoom level which will be displayed on the map. If omitted, or set to null, the minimum zoom from the current map type is used instead.

If we check your `map_zoom()` function, it's returning `8` on the first call.

If we use that `8` together with `minZoom` (instead of regular `zoom`) we'll get the desired result without calling `map_zoom()` a second time:

```
var defaultZoom = 8;
var allMarkers = new Array();
var mapOptions = {
    minZoom: defaultZoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

#### [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov0a2x38/1/)

---

#### Old answer:

1. Move the `map_zoom()` **outside** of `map_init()` so we can call it from anywhere
2. On `$('.accordiancontrol').click`, call the `map_zoom()` to update our zoom:

```js
$('.accordiancontrol').click(function(){
    if ($('#accordianarea' + thisId).is(":visible")) {
        // Close accordianarea
    }
    else {
        // Open accordianarea

        // Update zoom
        map_zoom();
    }
});
```

#### [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jvhomsk/1/)

Comment: Just did some further testing and the minZoom causes some other issues if the pins are placed further apart. basically it does what it should do. It sets a minimum zoom. the result is that the map centers over the pins but can't zoom out enough to see either of them.

Comment: Could you share an updates Fiddle so I can try it ? Maybe my old answer would be better if you'd update pins after the load. (Maybe include it in the OP?)

Answer (score 0):

"I can only imagine that the DOM has the collapsing parent div set to zero height and therefor Google Maps 'sees' this as zero all the way down the stack and sets bounds based on a zero height and width accordingly."

As you stated, zoom sets bounds based on a zero height and width.. What you can do is to call `map_init();` on map show. That way div has height and width and map gets proper zoom bounds

```
        $('.accordiancontrol').click(function(){
                        var thisId = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^\D+/g,"")
                        if ($('#accordianarea' + thisId).is(":visible"))
                        {
                           // Close accordianarea
                        }
                        else
                        {
                         map_init();
                        // Open accordianarea
                        }
                    });
```